# EntityFramework Relationship which way round

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have a customer which makes an inquiry (only one inquiry allowed) do I have:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ContactNumber {get;set;}

    public virtual Inquiry Inquiry {get;set;}
}
public class Inquiry
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public string Information {get;set;}
    public string Reason {get;set;}
}
```

or do I have it like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ContactNumber {get;set;}
}
public class Inquiry
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public string Information {get;set;}
    public string Reason {get;set;}

    public virtual Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
```

In the first scenario, I'm pretty sure if an `Inquiry` gets deleted the `Customer` will also get deleted, unless I use `public Guid? InquiryId {get;set;}` as well as the navigation property. This scenario does make more sense.

In the second scenario, I'm pretty sure if a `Customer` gets deleted the `Inquiry` will be deleted which is the desired effect. But it does make the navigation property a little redundant because you want to see what Enquiry a Customer has made `customer => inquiry`, rather then what Inquiries has a Customer made `inquiry.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Customer.Id.Equals(customerId))`.

In one way the `Delete On Cascade` property helps but the navigation property is redundant, however in the other way `Delete On Cascade` doesn't help (and needs more code to make it work in favour) but the navigation property is helpful.

So how do you decide which way to go?

I ***think*** the other downside to the first scenario, is that you have to manually delete the related `Inquiry` because when you delete the `Customer` it just ignores the cascade (because it has been turned off in code).

Comment: Can a customer have more than one inquiry?

Comment: Nope, I'll add that to the question!

Comment: In that case - I don't understand how the first option could even work. Did you mean for costumer to have an `IQueryable<Inquiry>` perhaps?

Comment: no.... It does work, it's a simple navigation property which places an `inquiry_id` field into the `Customer` table...

Comment: Can't a customer make an inquiry this week and another inquiry next week? If yes, what do you expect to happen with the old inquiry? Should it get deleted or only "detached" from the customer? Don't you want to hold a kind of inquiry history for the customer?

Comment: No, a contact only makes a single Inquiry. I don't want to hold a inquiry history if a customer gets deleted!

Comment: What kind of relationship do `Customer` and `Inquiry` have? One-to-one or one-to-many? Right now, your first code snippet will be mapped as one-to-many: A customer has *zero or one* inquiries, but an inquiry can be made by *many* customers. The second snippet will be mapped as many-to-one: A customer can have *many* inquiries, but an inquiry has *zero or one* customers.

Comment: I don't see how they are a one-to-many, i would use `List<T>` if there were many. A single customer makes a single inquiry. It's a one-to-one or zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the following infos from your question and your comments together...

- A customer has a single inquiry
- The effect is desired that when a customer gets deleted the related inquiry should be deleted as well
- You expect the relationship between customer and inquiry to be one-to-one or zero

...neither of the two models will fulfill these requirements without further mapping specification. However, you can achieve the goal by using the first model and adding an explicit mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.Inquiry)
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Related `Customer` and `Inquiry` will share the same primary key value, i.e. the primary key in `Inquiry` is the foreign key to `Customer`.

A few remarks about some incorrect assumptions:

> In the first scenario, I'm pretty sure if an Inquiry gets deleted the
>   Customer will also get deleted.

That's not correct because you don't have foreign key properties in your model in which case EF will assume an *optional* relationship and doesn't enable cascading delete by default.

> In the second scenario, I'm pretty sure if a Customer gets deleted the
>   Inquiry will be deleted.

Not correct for the same reason.

> It's a one-to-one or zero (relationship).

Both your first and your second scenario represent one-to-many relationships because that's the default relationship EF will assume if you have a navigation property only on one side of the relationship. It doesn't matter if you expose a collection on the other side or not to make it a one-to-many relationship. For example in the first scenario you could have two customers refering to the same inquiry which means that (conceptually and from database viewpoint) this inquiry will have two (= *many*) customers.